# Specify “_size” and “properties” both in mappings for Index

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to map mappings for documents in index. For that, I have created mappings with properties as of now.
But I also want to get the size of documents, for that, I found out that I need to enable "_size" field as shown here :
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/current/mapper-size-usage.html

My mappings object look like this as of now:

```
{
    "mappings": {
        "doc": {
            "properties": {
                ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

where should I add "_size" tag?
If I do something like this :

```
{
    "mappings": {
        "doc": {
            "properties": {
                ...
            },
            "_size": {
                "enabled": true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I get parsing exception.

If I place it inside properties, I cant get desired results.

Please Help.

Thanks

Comment: Basic question, did you install the plugin (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/current/mapper-size.html) ?

Comment: No, and only that was missing. Thankyou. Adding plugin worked

Comment: As the plugin documentation is integrated within the elasticsearch documentation is easy to think that it comes out of the box!

Answer (score 1):

The following works for me on an ES 6.0 cluster:

```
PUT index1

PUT index1/_mapping/type1
{
  "_size": {
    "enabled": true
  },
  "properties": {
    "latestLocation": {
      "properties": {
        "geoPoint": {
          "type": "geo_point"
        },
        "latestLocationTimestamp": {
          "type": "date"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

POST index1/type1
{
  "hello": "new document"
}

GET index1/type1/_search
{
    "script_fields": {
    "size": {
      "script": "doc['_size']"  
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thankyou for your response jhilden. I had to install plugin. my bad i was missing out on that.

Answer (score 0):

I had to install plugin. I thought this must be an inbuilt configuration parameter because I had the link to enable it. But it is not.

I had to install mapper-size plugin.